# Sobolev spaces and Holder continuity (or, fractional derivatives and singularities)

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have two specific questions. The first is the result I actually need, and the second would let me prove it.

EDIT: The second statement was wrong. I am keeping it for posterity. I am adding a third statement that reflects the minimum requirements of the proof I had in mind for the first statement.

**I need to show that for $0<\epsilon<1$ and $g\in H^{\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $\frac{g}{r^{\epsilon/2}}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.**

**The following statement was shown by responders to be false: It would help me to know whether it is true that if a compactly supported function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Holder continuous with $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^{\alpha}$ for some $0<\alpha<1$ and a constant $C>0$, then $f\in H^{\frac{n}{2}+\alpha}$.**

**Corrected version of second statement: It would help me to know whether it is true that if $f$ is an $H_0^{1+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ function with $f(0)=0$, $\frac{f}{r^{\epsilon/2}}$ is in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I don't know whether this is any easier or not, but we know that $f$ satisfies $|f(x)|<Cr^{\epsilon}$ in this case by the Sobolev imbedding theorem**

I have an intuition that $g$ is an $H^{\frac{n}{2}+s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function, then for $0<s<1$ and $g(0)=0$, or for $s\le0$ regardless, we should have that for any $\nu>\delta>0$, $\frac{g}{r^{\nu-\delta}}$ is in $H^{\frac{n}{2}+s-\nu}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, presuming that $g(0)=0$ if $s>0$.

This is based on the idea (which may or may not be correct) that fractional derivatives of singularities should increase their order at the same rate as integer derivatives (that is, if a rapidly decaying function $f$ has a singularity of order $|x-x_0|^{\alpha}$ at $x=x_0$, I think that $(\frac{d}{dx})^\alpha(f(x))$ should have a singularity of order $|x-x_0|^{\alpha+\beta}$ at $x=x_0$. I don't know how to prove this and probably don't need to, although it would likely be sufficient to get my result.

The converse of the second bolded statement is true and is known as the Sobolev imbedding theorem (see for example Theroem 3.26 in Strongly Elliptic Systems and Boundary Integral Equations by William McLean).

If anyone knows of a proof or reference for one of the bolded statements, that would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I don't think your second statement holds, at least not in this formulation, since for example nonzero constants are Hölder-continuous, but not even in $L^2$. I also faintly remember that even if you exclude that case, there are some pathologic examples of Hölder continuous functions that are not sobolev spaces even though the exponent seems to match, but I can't really recall them right now.

Comment: Second obviously false if you do not impose any conditions at infinity.

Comment: For the second case : $\sqrt{x}$ is holder continuous with $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$, but the function is not $H^1$.

Comment: Editing the second statement, thank you.

Comment: It is still not true; see my answer.

Comment: Yes... I will need to see if I can weaken that statement.

Comment: I cannot say whether the first statement is true (although this seems to be likely); but why $\epsilon/2$? I guess $\epsilon$ should be there.

Comment: I expect that $\epsilon$ doesn't work; think of $\epsilon=1$ (although I know I excluded that case). An $H^1$ function divided by r in general has a $\frac{1}{r}$ type singularity, so it is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Comment: Yes but if $f=r^{-a}$ near the origin with $a<1$ then everything works perfectly.

Comment: Do you mean that I could have written $\epsilon-\delta$ instead of $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, or that $\epsilon<1$ works differently from $\epsilon=1$? In the first case, I know that I could have but I have no motivation to write it like that. In the second case, I don't understand why and would like an explanation.

Comment: Yes I meant $\epsilon-\delta$, because $\epsilon$ would not work as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample to the second one: $n=4$, $f(x)=|x_1|\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is smooth and compactly supported and $\phi(0)=1$. Then $f''_{x_1x_1}=2\phi(x)\delta(x_1)+\dots$ is not in $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a valid counterexample. That $f$ is only in $H^1$, so my statement would only imply that $f''_{x_1 x_1}$ is in $H^{-1}$, which it is.

Comment: You probably have not read what you have written. Your second statement says that if $f$ is compacltly supported and Holder (which my $f$ is), then it is in $H^{n/2+\epsilon}$, i.e. in $H^{2+\epsilon}$ for $n=4$, but we see that my $f$ is not even in $H^2$ because the second derivative is not in $L^2$.

Comment: I was thinking of the wrong statement, let me look some more.